# How can I render 2 table side by side in a PDF report using itext 7.2.5

Tags: java, accessibility, itext7, nvda, pac

I want to render 2 tables side by side using itext 7.2.5 (java) without using nested tables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj96Q.png)

Can you help us on how we can design it using itext 7.2.5 without using nested tables. It should suppport accessibility i.e. PAC tool should mention no errors and nvda should read properly?

// ACCESSIBILITY : Added additonal parameter for image to support accessibility
public static Table getTrailingReturnsTable(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String alternateDescription) {

```
    float canvasWidth = (534 / 2) - 10; //canvas.getDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getWidth();
    float canvasHeight = 80f; //canvas.getDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getHeight();

    PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new PageSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDocument);

    // Create the first table
    Table table1 = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{1, 1, 1, 1}));
    Cell cell1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell L1,1"));
    Cell cell2 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell L1,2"));
    Cell cell3 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell L1,3"));
    Cell cell4 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell L1,4"));

    cell1.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    cell2.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    cell3.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    cell4.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);

    table1.addHeaderCell(cell1);
    table1.addHeaderCell(cell2);
    table1.addHeaderCell(cell3);
    table1.addHeaderCell(cell4);
    table1.addCell("Cell L2,1");
    table1.addCell("Cell L2,2");
    table1.addCell("Cell L2,3");
    table1.addCell("Cell L2,4");
    table1.addCell("Cell L3,1");
    table1.addCell("Cell L3,2");
    table1.addCell("Cell L3,3");
    table1.addCell("Cell L3,4");

    // Create a canvas for drawing on the template
    canvas.add(table1);
    return table1;
    /*
    Image image = new Image(pdfFormXObject);
    // Set any additional properties for the image, such as size
    image.setWidth(canvasWidth);
    image.setMinHeight(canvasHeight);

    // ACCESSIBILITY : Add Alternate description to an image
    image.getAccessibilityProperties().setAlternateDescription(alternateDescription);
    return image;
     */
}

public static Table getTrailingReturnsTable2(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String alternateDescription) {

    float canvasWidth = (534 / 2) - 10; //canvas.getDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getWidth();
    float canvasHeight = 80f; //canvas.getDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getHeight();

    PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new PageSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDocument);

    // Create the second table
    Table table2 = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{1, 1, 1}));
    Cell cellR1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell R1,1"));
    Cell cellR2 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell R1,2"));
    Cell cellR3 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Cell R1,3"));

    cellR1.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    cellR2.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    cellR3.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.TH);
    table2.addHeaderCell(cellR1);
    table2.addHeaderCell(cellR2);
    table2.addHeaderCell(cellR3);
    table2.addCell("Cell R2,1");
    table2.addCell("Cell R2,2");
    table2.addCell("Cell R2,3");

    // Create a canvas for drawing on the template
    canvas.add(table2);
    return table2;
    /*
    Image image = new Image(pdfFormXObject);
    // Set any additional properties for the image, such as size
    image.setWidth(canvasWidth);
    image.setMinHeight(canvasHeight);

    // ACCESSIBILITY : Add Alternate description to an image
    image.getAccessibilityProperties().setAlternateDescription(alternateDescription);
    return image;
     */
}
```

This is added to document
Div childDiv7 = new Div();
childDiv7.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GREEN).setMargin(0);

```
        Table table1 = getTrailingReturnsTable(pdfDocument, "Table1");
        Table table2 = getTrailingReturnsTable2(pdfDocument, "Table2");

        // Adjust the vertical alignment of the second table
        float verticalOffset = table1.getHeight().getValue() - table2.getHeight().getValue();
        table2.setMarginTop(verticalOffset);
        childDiv7.add(new Paragraph().add(table1.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(40f)).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.ORANGE)).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP)
                .add(new Paragraph().add(table2.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.YELLOW)).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP)).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP));

        document.add(childDiv7);
```

I have tried using div, which renders each table into a new row.
I tried using paragraph, it renders 2 tables side by side, but if the height of table2 is less than table 1, then the table2 is rendered from bottom.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcShb.png)

I tried using canvas, here I need to provide exact location of canvas. I tried converting table added canvas to image, but it did not render properly.